# How do you properly execute "mvn clean" inside a project?

Tags: java, maven, maven-lifecycle

I'm trying to clean, build, and package my project, but I keep getting this error:

```java
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (auto-clean) on project Presentation: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean for parameter retryOnError: Cannot find 'retryOnError' in class org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.CleanMojo -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (auto-clean) on project Presentation: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean for parameter retryOnError: Cannot find 'retryOnError' in class org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.CleanMojo
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:220)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginConfigurationException: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean for parameter retryOnError: Cannot find 'retryOnError' in class org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.CleanMojo
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.populatePluginFields(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:605)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
... 19 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.ComponentConfigurationException: Cannot find 'retryOnError' in class org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.CleanMojo
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.CompositeBeanHelper.setProperty(CompositeBeanHelper.java:252)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.converters.composite.ObjectWithFieldsConverter.processConfiguration(ObjectWithFieldsConverter.java:101)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.BasicComponentConfigurator.configureComponent(BasicComponentConfigurator.java:32)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.populatePluginFields(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:575)
... 22 more
```

I've been trying to figure this out for myself for a while now. I have the project set up to auto clean, and it's exactly how Apache instructed to do so in the pom file(s), but I'll include that as well.

```xml
<project>
    <build>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnError>false</failOnError>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>auto-clean</id>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>clean</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        ...
    </build>
<project>
```

I am lost here. Obviously, it has something to do with 'retryOnError', but that's not something I added myself. Where would I find that?

Also, I'm using Maven 3.2.5 if that helps.

Comment: Do you really need a "plugin" to clean up? I think `mvn clean` will do the trick...and for your purpose, executing (at project's root level) `mvn clean package` or `mvn clean verify` is enough

Comment: That's what I was trying to do, originally. mvn clean package results in the same error, as well as mvn clean verify.

Comment: the stacktrace is because the `maven-clean-plugin`; can you comment that part and try `mvn clean`?

Comment: When I do that it says the 'build.plugins.plugin.artifactid' is missing.

Comment: You must comment from `<!-- <plugin> ... </plugin> -->`; looks like you did it from `<artifactId>` onwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the version of the clean plugin you are explicitly configuring differs to the one shipped with maven (or a similar mismatch in default properties)

As the comments above suggest i would remove the entire section of :

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <failOnError>false</failOnError>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>auto-clean</id>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

and then run a mvn clean / mvn clean package.

If you are set on using the plugin you should also try setting the property manually in the config as the below:

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <failOnError>false</failOnError>
        <retryOnError>true</retryOnError>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>auto-clean</id>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This still doesn't work :( I get the same stacktrace, whether I comment out the `plugin` and run `mvn clean` or add the `<retryOnError>` parameter.

Comment: Can you share the code in GitHub or something similar? You shouldn't get the same stack trace since it's related with something you don't have (assuming you commented your `<plugin>` declaration for `maven-clean-plugin`)

Comment: I can't share it, it's commercial software. That's a good way to get myself fired. ;) I can tell you this, though, when I clean from eclipse it does it without a problem. it's just from the command line or the maven-invoker from Apache, and everything else works when I don't include the plugin. It's only clean that is broken.

Comment: Well, thanks for your answer. It was helpful for understanding Maven a bit more, so it was helpful! Thanks again.

Comment: What is exactly broken? maven-invoker-plugin? Why do you need such supplemental options in maven-clean-plugin?

Comment: In maven there are no plugins shipped with it.

Answer (score 1):

@ɐuıɥɔɐɯ is right.

I would also try removing the auto-clean plugin configuration in your pom.xml, as it may be more work to figure out why it is causing problems than it is worth.  For now on, I would simply run the following command in the root folder of your project:

```
mvn clean package
```

That should run your goals listed in your pom.xml, and clean your "target" subdirectory, replacing it with the newest code.

See http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-clean-project-with-maven/ for more information.

Comment: The clean is a life cycle which is called. The maven-clean-plugin is bound by default to this life cycle (clean) which means it is executed. And there is no tool built in for `clean package` this is only the life cycles which are executed.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that for me and for everyone else.  I have edited my post accordingly.